# Is (lambda (x) ... ) with parenthesis placed in a certain way used for limiting scope?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

A classic enumeration using unfold:

```
(unfold-left (lambda (x)
               (if (> x 10)
                   (#;no values)
                   (+ x 1)))
             #;from 0)
```

===> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

if limiting the scope is not needed is there any way to just write x without the lambda?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking

Comment: No, `lambda` is not used for limiting scope. It's used for defining a function.

Comment: what im asking is there anyway to write the x in the above without the lambda around it for the unfold to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

`unfold` is implemented like this:

```
(define (unfold p f g seed (tail-gen (λ (_) '())))
  (let recur ((seed seed))
    (if (p seed)
        (tail-gen seed)
        (cons (f seed)
              (recur (g seed))))))
```

As you can see `p`, `f`, `g`, and `tail-gen` are all procedures since they get surrounded by parentheses in the implementation. If they are not procedures you will get an `application: not a procedure` error.

You are using `unfold` wrong. you need a procedure that takes the current value and return wether or not you are finished. Second is a procedure that takes the seed and return what value to collect and the third is a procedure to create the next seed. The optional `tail-gen` takes the seed and creates the tail where the empty list will be used if not provided. Here is how you make a list from 0 to 10:

```
#lang racket    
(require srfi/1)
(require srfi/26)

(unfold (cut > <> 10) identity add1 0) 
; ==> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

And of course, `(range 11)` gives the same answer.